# Amazon MQ does not receiving any queue message

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I have a NodeJS program using the `mqtt` NPM plugin to send messages to Amazon MQ. I configured the queue and subscribed, and then publish the message. [Here](https://gist.github.com/amicming/8ef8e561a19a4a25a3af838ccdca402c) is the code.

The listener uses the OpenWire JMS client, and I'm sending messages using either MQTT or WSS. In both cases the JMS client is not receiving any message.

If I write NodeJS code for the receiver it is working.

Does the JMS client have to use either MQTT / WSS to receive the message? Does the protocol matter here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT is a Topic based messaging protocol and as such the subscribers to messages sent from the MQTT publishers need to be listening on a Topic and not a Queue.  Topics are publish / subscribe to when no subscribes exist the messages will be discarded unless there exists a durable Topic subscription prior to the message having been produced so be aware of that.

In ActiveMQ there are ways of [routing](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations) messages from one destination to another so you could take advantage of that to route messages or you could you something like a [Camel](https://camel.apache.org/) route to forward the Topic messages sent from MQTT clients to a Queue.

Comment: Can I say I have only one choice, that is OpenWire For Queue-based messaging protocol?

Comment: No, you can choose, STOMP, AMQP, or OpenWire based on you messaging client needs, and you can use MQTT if you choose to use Camel or internal broker destination forwarding.

Comment: Thanks Tim, finally I fixed this one using STOMP. appreciate your help